# Remove several select option with JS when no html access

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```
    <select id="color-filter" onchange="js_color_filter_changed()" name="color-filter">
    <option selected="selected" value="none">---</option>
    <option style="background-color:#A8314F" value="#A8314F"> </option>
    <option style="background-color:#CEF0FF" value="#CEF0FF"> </option>
    <option style="background-color:#D1FFB3" value="#D1FFB3"> </option>
    <option style="background-color:#FFA4A4" value="#FFA4A4"> </option>
    </select>
```

and I would like remove/hide for example some option with cross compatibility browser and without Jquery. I don't have access to html but I can add code in external JS file.

I found this solution which work well:

http://jsfiddle.net/vpV3q/4/

but when I change value this don't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/vpV3q/5/

I suppose is because value contain hash tag. I'm a JS newbie...any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this changes in your example :
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vpV3q/6/)

```
var ary = ['#DADAD2','#CEF0FF'];
$('[name=year] option').filter(function () {
    return ($.inArray(this.value,ary) > -1);
}).remove();
```

1. Add quotes to values ​​in the array
2. The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer. Removed

If in your "real" html the combo is : `<select name="color-filter"  ... >`

Change :

```
$('[name=year] option') ...
```

by

```
$('[name=color-filter] option') ...
```

Comment: Why not simply: `$(ary.join(',')).remove();`

Comment: I tested but this don't work at my side. Maybe is because the Onchange? If yes I don't know what this event do and where is related code. Probably in another JS file where I don't have access. I must investigate..

Comment: @DavidThomas , sorry but I cannot understand how to use this code inside the op's example.

Comment: @dotcom27 If onchange method has a problem, that problem does not affect to example. onchange fires when you change the value inside combo See http://jsfiddle.net/vpV3q/7/ . In this case, fails when you select another option... msg:"functionInOtherJS is not defined"